# How to stop Firestore emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I have started Firebase emulator locally using the suggested command `gcloud emulators firestore start --host-port=localhost:8081`. The app successfully connects to it and reads/writes data. Then I press `Ctrl+C` to stop the emulator as recommended in the [official Google article](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/emulator) and nothing happens - the emulator is still up, the terminal keeps showing emulator logs.

My operating system: **Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS**, Google Cloud SDK version: **441.0.0**, `cloud-firestore-emulator` version: **1.18.1**

Comment: What is the operating system? Open another terminal/command-prompt/browser-window and connect to port 8081. Depending on the OS or TCP stack configuration,  and application might not receive CTRL-C while sleeping on a network call.

Comment: @JohnHanley Operating system: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. My app successfully connects to the emulator on port 8081, it isn't an issue here. I just cannot stop the emulator by pressing `Ctrl+C`

Comment: Try connecting again after pressing CTRL-C.

Comment: @JohnHanley the app still can connect and query/write data to the Firestore even after hitting `Ctrl+C` in the emulator terminal. It shows that `Ctrl+C` seems to be ignored by the emulator.